How to start with GIT in delphi (with existing code)
Since I am completely lost in this new topic, I need to ask this stupid question (as no guide covers this understandably for me).
I have:

Delphi code on my disk
a GitHub account
GIT downloaded and configured in Delphi IDE

What are the steps I have to do to get my code into a web-repo?

create an empty repo at www.github.com

clone the empty repo to my dev-machine
a. to which folder? A blank one, or to the folder my code is in already?


What comes next?
I have played around but never got to successfully update my repos in the cloud. How can I remove the GIT configuration from my projects to start new?

If your code already exists locally, don't create an empty one in github, start from your code root folder with git init, but take time to read one or two tutorials, this is extensively covered.

When you create a new repository on github, just after clicking on "Create" it gives you the command lines to follow to push existing code in the newly created github repo. Just do some training on dummy repo and dummy files (except if you are sure to have a backup of your Delphi source code). Tip: if you have existing code, don't click on "create a README" checkbox when creating the repo (it will create a commit with it and that will make your life more complicated). Create this README.md file yourself after.

You might want to use TortoiseGit or a similar tool extending the Windows Explorer context menu

Don't attempt to think about git for delphi. Spend some time learning git.


I have played around but never got to successfully update my repos in the cloud. How can I remove the GIT configuration from my projects to start new?

If you're asking how to start with a brand new repository and remove your current Git configurations, you need to delete the hidden folder .git from your project directory, open Git bash, and run git init. However, perform this operation only if you don't want to keep the current history of changes (if any is present).
Instead, if you want to maintain your current repository, and you're asking how to remove the configurations to track a remote repository, you can run git remote in the Git bash and remove each result.
# listing the remotes added to your repository
git remote

# removing each remote returned by the command git remote
git remote remove <remote1>
...
git remote remove <remoteN>

Once you've brought your project to the desired state, you can go to https://github.com/ and create a new empty repository. To do that, just define the repository's name and the visibility (public or private). Do not check "Add a README.md file" or pick an option for "Add .gitignore" and "Choose a license". Once the repository has been created, copy the generated link (something in the form https://github.com/your-user/your-repo.git), open a Git terminal from your project directory, and run:
git remote add origin https://github.com/your-user/your-repo.git

Now, if you want to push your local work or fetch somebody's changes, you just need to enter:
# pushing the current branch changes to origin remote
git push origin

# fetching the changes of another branch
git fetch origin <other_branch>


so I cannot rely on the IDE options to commit/push but should rather user an external tool or cmdline, right?

@WolfgangBures I recommend to avoid the Delphi IDE's tools for version control, and use a separate tool for that, such as GitHub Desktop. I have tried Delphi's built-in tools and they add nothing of value, and are very rough and lacking.

@WolfgangBures if your IDE provides a graphical interface for Git, I'm sure you can reproduce the commands above also from your IDE. I've preferred sharing the Git commands, first of all because I am not familiar with Delphi's IDE, and second because like so you're not bound to a specific graphical interface. You can always run these shell commands, regardless of the GUI you'll deal with.
